# how to fix the profanity_filter string cast error

Tags: string, list, flutter, profanity

I am trying to use ProfanityFilter in flutter, to filter bad words in a review content, which is a string. ProfanityFilter has a list of censored words, which I want to pass along with the list of swear words not included in a [LDNOOBW list](https://github.com/LDNOOBW/List-of-Dirty-Naughty-Obscene-and-Otherwise-Bad-Words). However, since the content is a string, I use a cast, and then I get cast error: type 'ProfanityFilter' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast.

```
TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.comment_outlined, color: 
 Colors.white60, size: 20,),
              hintText: Languages
                  .of(context)
                  .revHint,
              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(),
            ),
            maxLines: null,
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                val = ProfanityFilter.filterAdditionally(badString) as String;
                content = val;
                viewModel.setDescription(content);
              });
            }
          ),
```

How do I pass string to a list, scan and then parse the censored list to a string back? Or is there a better and easier way to censore bad words? A map maybe? Thank you! Very new to flutter and coding.

Comment: Are you using this textformfield to add new bad words, or are you trying to check if the string entered into the textformfield contains bad words?

Comment: to check if the string entered has bad words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your response in comments, you are using the wrong method to do this. You should be using `.hasProfanity`.

Methods

hasProfanity - Detect if a string contains profanity

Use the hasProfanity() method of the filter instance. Pass in the string to be tested.

Example

```
final filter = ProfanityFilter();
String badString = 'you are an ass';
filter.hasProfanity(badString); //Returns true.
```

If you want to get a list of the bad words in the string then use the `.getAllProfanity()` method.

In your code, 'val' will contain the string entered by the user and this is what you pass to the method, not 'badString'.

Comment: oh... so, if i want to mask all the profanity in the review, I just pass: setState(() {content = filter.censor(val); viewModel.setDescription(content);});?. Thank you! tried it and it is not censoring...

Comment: I never mentioned the censor method and I don't use the package myself. I am just reading and interpreting the package information posted in its readMe. I think you need to study that information more closely and maybe look at the example on the github repo. It's all explained pretty clearly imho.

Comment: I think your problem now is how you are handling the 'content' variable. I would think censor has worked. You can test that by printing the variable to your console after the method has run or by checking its value using the debugger.

Comment: it is working. just had to add some if, else conditions for some words. thank you!

Comment: Great, glad I helped.